# glibc detected - double free or corruption

Tags: c, arrays, memory-leaks, glibc

I am writing a simple stack program in C that has a flexible array of void*'s at the end. When more elements are needed to push into the array, I am using realloc() to make a new stack, free the old one and assign the new to the old one.(I don't have a pop() function at the moment).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Stack
{
    int top, length;
    void* start_ptr[];
} Stack;

Stack* init_stack(int n_items)
{
    Stack* stack;
    stack = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3 + sizeof(void*) * n_items);

    stack->top = -1;
    stack->length = n_items;

    return stack;
}

Stack* increase_stacksize(Stack* stack, int n_itemsToAdd)
{
    Stack* newstack;    
    newstack = realloc(stack, sizeof(*stack) + sizeof(void*) * (n_itemsToAdd + stack->length));

    if(newstack != NULL)
         //printf("\nDebug print - array reallocated\n");

    free(stack);
    stack = newstack;

    stack->length += n_itemsToAdd;

    return stack;
}

Stack* push(Stack* stack, void* item)
{
    if(stack->top + 1 == stack->length){

        stack = increase_stacksize(stack, 10);
    }

    int pos = stack->top + 1;

    stack->start_ptr[pos] = item;
    ++(stack->top);

    return stack;
}

void printstack(Stack* stack)
{
     printf("Number of items in the stack = %d\n", stack->top + 1);
     printf("Capacity of the stack = %d\n", stack->length);

     printf("Elements in the stack are: \n");

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= stack->top; i++){
        int* item_ptr;
        void* address;

        address = stack->start_ptr[i];

        item_ptr = (int*)address;

        printf("Position = %d, Item = %d \n", i, *item_ptr);
    }
}

int main(void)
{    
    Stack* stack;
    stack = init_stack(5);

    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        stack = push(stack, (void*)(a+i));
    }

    printstack(stack);

    free(stack);

    return 1;
}
```

Problem is when I free() the stack in main() after I am all done a message gets printed in stderr :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x096ee008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb7721fd4]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x9c)[0xb772387c]
./prog[0x8048731]
./prog[0x8048461] 
 ======= Memory map: ========
```

The output upto printstack() is fine though. Even if I remove the free(stack) line, I get a runtime error in [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Xqdfmq), but there's no stderr message. I am guessing it might be something due to the zero size array. What could be the issue here?

Comment: The runtime error in ideone could be because you return 1 from `main`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`realloc` frees your old block if necessary so you should remove the `free(stack)` line in `increase_stacksize`

Comment: Also the 'if newstack==NULL' line needs deleting. Note that the line after it is commented out!!

Comment: oh forgot to uncomment the line. thanks for answering. I didn't know that. K&R writes use free if the memory is allocated with malloc, calloc or realloc. Couldn't totally understand what realloc does as it just says realloc "changes" the size. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You `realloc` and then free the original `stack`. Just remove the `free` there:

```
free(stack);   // remove this line
stack = newstack;
```

After a successful `realloc`, the address returned by the function is not guaranteed to be the same as the original. If it's the same, you end up freeing the memory twice. If it's not the same, you end up freeing an unallocated memory location.

In short, don't `free` the original after a `realloc`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining me what realloc really does.